# Ordenar tabela PHP

Tags: php, mysql

estou tentando ordenar uma tabela que está em PhP e que puxa os dados do banco de dados, tentei com js chamado sorttable, porém não funcionou, a tabela está com esse código:

```
            echo '<table class="sortable">'; 
            echo "<tr><th>Empresa</th><th>Atividade</th><th>Telefone</th><th>Licença</th><th>Contato</th><th>#</th></tr>";
            while ($row_empresas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_empresas)){
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $row_empresas['nomeCliente'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row_empresas['documento'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row_empresas['telefone'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row_empresas['cidade'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row_empresas['email'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>';
                echo '<a href="'.base_url().'index.php/base2/visualizar/'.$row_empresas['idClientes'].'" style="margin-right: 1%" class="btn tip-top" title="Ver mais detalhes"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i></a>';
                echo '<a href="'.base_url().'index.php/base2/editar/'.$row_empresas['idClientes'].'" style="margin-right: 1%" class="btn btn-info tip-top" title="Editar Cliente"><i class="icon-pencil icon-white"></i></a>';
            echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';

            }
            echo '</table>';
```

Como eu poderia arrumar a mesma para que pudesse ser ordenada?

Comment: Não pode já pedir a tabela ordernada com `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Então, mas depois que ela está com os dados dentro da tabela, queria poder ordenar dentro dela, não por order by, não sei se fui muito claro

Comment: Pode não ser uma solução mas [isto](https://datatables.net/) pode ajuda-lo. Pode não ser o que pediu mas Datatables podem oferecer-lhe muitas opções.

Answer (score 2):

Eu uso esse [Sorttable](https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable), exemplo:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sorttable</title>
        <!-- Importa o JS -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Ativa o sorttable na tabela -->
        <table class="sortable">
            <thead>
                <tr><th>Person</th><th>Monthly pay</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr><td>Jan Molby</td><td>£12,000</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Steve Nicol</td><td>£8,500</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Steve McMahon</td><td>£9,200</td></tr>
                <tr><td>John Barnes</td><td>£15,300</td></tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr><td>TOTAL</td><td>£45,000</td></tr>
            </tfoot>
          </table>
    </body>
```

É bem simples de usar, e na documentação possui mais usos avançados (fazer com que não ordene por determinada coluna, manter os ícones visíveis, mudar os ícones, ...) e explicações